# Picking a certain item from an array in a dropdown list then showing it as the first item and in alphabetic order.

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

My dropdown should contain a list of all the items in an array. However they should not be organized from A-Z but choosing an item should make it the first item in the list, and the list should continue alphabetically from there. How can I achieve this ?

enter code here

```
var array =["cellphone", "camara", "computer", "mouse", "track-pad", "usb", "screen"] 
enter code here

<select id="dropdownList">
<option>cellphone</option>
<option>camara</option>
<option>computer</option>
<option>mouse</option>
<option>track-pad</option>
<option>usb</option>
<option>screen</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is my solution, below, too advanced for you? It is written as a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:
Check the **snippet below**

```js
var array = ["cellphone", "camara", "computer", "mouse", "track-pad", "usb", "screen"];

var select = document.getElementById('dropdownList');
select.addEventListener('change', function() {

  array.sort(function(val1, val2) {
    return val1.localeCompare(val2);
  });

  array.unshift(this.value);
  array.splice(array.lastIndexOf(this.value), 1);

  var values = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    values += '<option>' + array[i] + '</option>';

  }

  select.innerHTML = values;
  console.log(array);
  console.log(this.value);

});
```

```html
<select id="dropdownList">
  <option>cellphone</option>
  <option>camara</option>
  <option>computer</option>
  <option>mouse</option>
  <option>track-pad</option>
  <option>usb</option>
  <option>screen</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does the selected value get lost when we replace all of the option elements?

Comment: @Calvin Belden nope, as it becomes default, edited snippet, can check in console

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a couple jQuery plugins to make this task easy and applicable to any select box. This is the most concise jQuery code. It is optimal, bacause we never remove the options and create new ones. Instead, we overwrite their values.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.populateSelect = function(items, valueField, displayField) {
    return this.append(items.map(function(item, index) {
      return $('<option>', {
        value : valueField   != null ? item[valueField]   : index,
        text  : displayField != null ? item[displayField] : item
      });
    }));
  };
  $.fn.selectedValue = function() {
    return this.find('option:selected').val();
  };
  $.fn.sortOptionsBy = function(key) {
    var options = this.find('option'), arr = options.map(function(_, opt) {
      return { text: opt.text, value: opt.value };
    }).get().sort(function(o1, o2) {
      return o1[key] > o2[key] ? 1 : o1[key] < o2[key] ? -1 : 0;
    });
    options.each(function(idx, opt) { $.extend(opt, arr[idx]); });
    return this;
  };
  $.fn.moveToIndex = function(val, idx) {
    this.find('option[value="' + val + '"]').insertBefore(this.find('option:eq(' + idx + ')'));
    return this.prop('selectedIndex', idx);
  };
  $.fn.moveSelectedToTop = function() {
    var selected = this.selectedValue();
    return this.sortOptionsBy('text').moveToIndex(selected, 0);
  }
}(jQuery));

var data = ["cellphone", "camera", "computer", "mouse", "track-pad", "usb", "screen"];
$('#dropdown-list').populateSelect(data).on('change', function(e, item) {
  $(e.target).moveSelectedToTop();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="dropdown-list"></select>
```